# How can I customize FOSUserBundle?

Tags: routes, fosuserbundle, symfony-3.2

After struggling with symfony and FOSUserBundle i have decided to ask your help

I have  followed the tutorial of FOSUserBundle and it all works fine ,but now I have to use FOSUserBundle  differently ,

The login page of FOSUserBundle Should be the first page of my web application it means the index.html.twig (In my case it's a web application the user (admin access to admin space and user to  user space ) should authenticate before acceding to my application.

So how can I configurate my project to begin with login.html.twig of the FOSUserBundle 
I have followed the officiel documentation : http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html

I can't see it !!

Comment: Can you try to change the render of the controller with '/' route, replace it with a render of your login page.

Comment: I have tried that but I think it's more complicated then that !!

Answer (score 2):

Add this line to your file security.yml :

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
```